# Javascript/jquery - go 2 levels up in the dom (let's call this object "A") and then apply css to one of the children of "A"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I didn't find a way to solve this problem.

`$( ".child" ).closest( ".parent").closest(".grandparent")`

And when I have this object, I would like to apply some css to one of it's childen (let's call mygodfather)

Thank you very much for your help!

````
.grandparent.mygodfather{
background-color: red
}```
````

Comment: Why can't you just use `$( ".child" ).closest(".grandparent")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`jQuery.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) can be used in order to select the "godfather" element:

```
$( ".child" ).closest(".grandparent").find('.godfather').css('background-color', 'red')
```

Demo:

```js
$( ".child" ).closest(".grandparent").find('.godfather').css('background-color', 'red')
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1rem 3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grandparent">
  Grandparent
  <div class="parent">
    Parent
    <div class="child">
      Child
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="godfather">
    Godfather
  </div>

</div>
```

Edit: simplified as suggested by @Andy Hoffman: only one call to `.closest` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to traverse up the DOM tree (in your case to get "parent" and "grandparent") and then use [`jQuery.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) or [`jQuery.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to select the correct child element (in your case "mygodfather")

The resulting code would be:

```
$(".child").parent().parent().next(".mygodfather");
```